# Angular FlexLayout aligning select element and fab-mini on same line for all devices but un-alignment on boundaries

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to align 2 elements on same line. Alignment is fine but for different devices sometimes search fab-mini goes outside the view and for some devices fab-mini comes very much inside. How to align fab-mini properly aligned to the right side and input element alight to the left for every device.

```
<section>
  <div fxLayout fxLayout.xs="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
    <div fxFlex="96%" fxFlex.xs="90%" fxFlex.md="90%">
      <ng-select
        [placeholder]="to.placeholder"
        [formControl]="formControl"
        [items]="items"
        [addTag]="addTag"
        [hideSelected]="true"
        multiple="true"
        bindLabel="name"
      >
      </ng-select>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="4%" fxFlex.xs="10%" fxFlex.md="90%">
      <a href="javaScript:void(0)" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="openSearchTable()">
        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Current situation
**For web**
[image]

**For tablets and phones**
[image]

Comment: Check `input` and `icon` line height

Comment: @Awais : Yes how to fix this ? :)

Comment: I mean inspect `icon` and `input` line height! are they equal ? and also try `fxLayoutAlign="start center"`

Comment: No they are not equal. I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: you are using gap so you need to subtract gap in as fxflex="calc(4%-10px)